# Display common control on multiple tabs without losing state of the control C#

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have three tab panels in a Tab container

```
<ajax:TabContainer ID="tabContainer" runat="server"   OnActiveTabChanged="tabContainer_ActiveTabChanged" AutoPostBack="true">

<ajax:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabPanel1" TabIndex="1" HeaderText="tabPanel1HeaderText"></ajax:TabPanel>

<ajax:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabPanel2" TabIndex="2" HeaderText="tabPanel2HeaderText" visible="false">
some commone controls</ajax:TabPanel>

<ajax:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabPanel3" TabIndex="3" HeaderText="tabPanel3HeaderText"></ajax:TabPanel>

</ajax:TabContainer>
```

I am trying to use tabPanel2 as my dummy column to display common controls on tabPanel2 on both tabPanel1 and tabPanel3 like this

```
string tab = tabContainer.ActiveTab.HeaderText;
        switch (tab)
        {
            case "tabPanel1.HeaderText":

                tabPanel2.Visible = true;
                tabPanel1.Visible = false;
                tabPanel3.Visible = true;

                tabPanel2.HeaderText = "tabPanel1.HeaderText";
                tabContainer.ActiveTabIndex = tabPanel2.TabIndex;
                break;

            case "tabPanel3.HeaderText":
                tabPanel2.Visible = true;
                tabPanel1.Visible = true;
                tabPanel3.Visible = false;

                tabPanel2.HeaderText = "tabPanel3.HeaderText";
                tabContainer.ActiveTabIndex = tabPanel2.TabIndex;
                break;

             }
```

Now I have another tab panel

```
    <ajax:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabPanel4" TabIndex="4" HeaderText="tabPanel4HeaderText"></ajax:TabPanel>
```

And I want to display tabePanel2 control on tabPanel4 as well. Is there a way to play with visibility to make tab2 appear in the same position of tab1,tab3 and tab4  by making those respective tab invisible?

Comment: I f you need to show **exactly** that control, you probably should use the `jquery` to switch the html for this tab. In other case you should create a copy of control, as there can be only one parent for a ASP.NET control in page tree.